# Ionic2 open alert on a Text input

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am opening an alert on an  as :

```
<ion-item [class.custom-error]="!logForm.controls.category_name.valid &&submitattempt">
    <ion-label fixed>Task Category <ion-icon name="ios-arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
    <div *ngIf="!logForm.controls.category_name.valid  && (logForm.controls.category_name.dirty || submitattempt)">
        <span style="color: red">*</span>>
    </div>
    </ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" id="category_name" class="form-control" formControlName="category_name" (click)="category()" [(ngModel)]="category_name"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

It is working fine when running on browser but on running it in app first text input opens and then on again clicking popup opens.

So how can i overcome this, I have to use it like this only using formControlName and formClass and all to apply conditional validation..

This is my onclick function:

```
 category(){
    var options = {
  title: 'Choose a task category',
  inputs: [],
  message: 'Which category do you like?',
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      role: 'cancel',
      handler: () => {
        console.log('Cancel clicked');
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Ok',
      handler: data => {

    }
  ]
};

// Now we add the radio buttons
for(let i=0; i< this.categories.length; i++) {
  options.inputs.push({ name : 'options', value: this.categories[i], label: this.categories[i], type: 'radio' });
}

// Create the alert with the options
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create(options);
alert.present();
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after i solved my problem hope it helps some body.

```
 <ion-item>
        <ion-label fixed>Category <ion-icon name="ios-arrow-forward"></ion-icon></ion-label>
        <ion-select formControlName="category_name" [(ngModel)]="category_name" (ionChange)="category_sel();" >
            <ion-option value="{{category_name}}" *ngFor="let category_name of categories">{{category_name}}</ion-option>

        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```